# apache rewrite rules do not work properly when url ends with slash

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wanted to redirect urls like **`example.com`** to **`https://www.example.com`**. I tried the following apache rewrite rules, but it did not work properly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I entered **`example.com`** in the web browser, it correctly redirected to **`https://www.example.com`**, but if I entered **`example.com/`**, i.e. with a trailing slash, it partially redirected to **`https://example.com`** without preceding **`www`**.

So how to configure the rewrite rules?

Comment: There is no difference in the request sent from browser to server whether you put trailing slash after the hostname or not (`/` will always be sent).

Comment: They are different in terms of the different result mentioned. When a slash is explicitly added, it did not redirect to www.